# create-react-app throws error: "Missing dependencies in package.json"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

So I'm trying to run reactjs official tutorial and with the first line of code:

```
 npx create-react-app react-tutorial
```

...I get the following error:

```
npx: installed 91 in 12.692s

Creating a new React app in /home/foo/projects/react-tutorial.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.12.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[-----] 1/1297Missing dependencies in package.json
```

I read some where else to clean or force clean npm cache but that didn't work either:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

I'm on ubuntu running latest node (10.16.0) I also tried with 8.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the error is discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5918):

> This seems to be a Yarn issue.

The workaround is to use npm instead of yarn:

```
create-react-app myproject --use-npm
```

If installing with npm you experience the following error:

> npm ERR! cb() never called!

increase the ulimit in your .bashrc, .bash_profile, and/or .profile by updating (or removing) the below command:

```
ulimit -n 20000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using yarn instead of npm. Try `--use-npm` flag like this :

```
npx create-react-app react-tutorial --use-npm
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by installing `yarn` and then:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Some people uninstalled `yarn` and used `npm` instead, I am not sure why `npm` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade **npm** version on your system.
Also upgrade your node.js version to the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue here all steps are written look into it..
reinstall npm(react) using the following command
`npm install -g npm-reinstall`
to some users, it may ask to audit fix do it
`npm audit fix`
`npm audit fix --force`
after it will take 2-5 min then write our command for creating a new project in react using npm
`npx create-react-app amazon --use-npm`
After the common step to start the server
`cd amazon`
`npm start`