# Why does create-react-app give "Missing dependencies in package.json" message?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm

**What's the problem:**

I recently started learning reactjs. while creating a new react app, the build fails and only a package.json file is created.

```
    > PS D:\react-projects> npx create-react-app app-name Creating a new
    > React app in D:\react-projects\exercount.
    > 
    > Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
    > react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
    > 
    > 
    > added 1396 packages, and changed 1 package in 9m 203 packages are
    > looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
    > Missing dependencies in package.json
```

**What I used:**

- VS CODE 1.69
- Windows 10 Home single language Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044
- Node v16.16
- NPM v8.13.2

**when did i encounter it:**
I tried to create my first react app by following the reactjs official tutorial. I opened vs code in administrator mode and ran the following command in the terminal

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

while this worked fine in my friends linux laptop, it failed in my windows one.
All it does is throw a "Missing dependancies in package.json" message and only builds a folder with one package.json file.

**What have i tried:**

- various commands to create the app like - npx, npm create-react-app and create-react-app itself
- have run those commands with and without the "-use--npm" flag
- forced flushed the npm cache
- uninstalled and reinstalled vs code, npm and node

All i found online were a few similar questions with only small number of them with answers. I have tried all of them and nothing worked.If you know what could be causing this, it would be helpful.

Screenshots:

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFBL3.png)

[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9TYY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app throws error: "Missing dependencies in package.json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651913/create-react-app-throws-error-missing-dependencies-in-package-json)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski no, it doesn't. I've already tried everything in that thread. Nothing worked.

Comment: It looks like you already have `package.json` before even running `create-react-app`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski not really. I created a new folder with nothing in it before using the `npx create-react-app appname` command. Before running the command, the folder is empty and after running it, there is a single folder with the appname i used in the npx command. And inside it is only one `package.json` file left behind. Nothing else. I'm honestly stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. The problem was resolved by downgrading npm to version 8.3.0 `npm install -g npm@8.3.0`

Comment: Seems like a quick fix more than a solution

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it is :( I agree. But for now, just this worked in the same situation