# missing dependencies in package.json file , when I am running npx create-react-app name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, package.json

[missing dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H0MF.png)

What Shall I do Kindly help me with this.
I have reinstalled node, I have done all the solutions already listed on internet.

I have tried all the solutions listed on net.
I have installed create-react-app globally and whatever solutions already present on net.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app throws error: "Missing dependencies in package.json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651913/create-react-app-throws-error-missing-dependencies-in-package-json)